# React Native Web with Next JS and React Navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, next.js

I am trying to decide on the best way to set up routing in my React Native Web project. I am using expo and followed this guide to use Next JS https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-nextjs/ so I have App.js like this:

```
import index from "./pages/index";
import alternate from "./pages/alternate";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    index,
    alternate
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "index"
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default AppContainer;
```

My concern is how best to handle routing. I have my index.js page setup like this currently.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Button, Text, View } from 'react-native'


export default function App ({navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      {/* Native route */}
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("alternate")}
      />

      {/* Web route */}
      <Text style={styles.link} accessibilityRole="link" href={`/alternate`}>
        A universal link
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

As you can see this is currently requiring separate code to render a Native vs Web route. I am wondering what is the best way to handle this sort of rendering. I looked into using [React Navigation for web](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/web-support.html) and wouldn't be opposed to this but it seems like I should probably stick with the Next Router.

Thanks in advance for any advice on handling conditional rendering like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reactnavigation web support for that

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/web-support.html

```
import { createSwitchNavigator } from "@react-navigation/core";
import { createBrowserApp } from "@react-navigation/web";

const MyNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(routes);

const App = createBrowserApp(MyNavigator);

// now you can render "App" normally
```

Comment: I was looking into react navigation with web support and wanted to see if it was possible to run it side by side native code using Next JS. I will give this a try.

Comment: I can confirm this does seem to work. App can be conditionally created like this const App =
  Platform.OS === "web"
    ? createBrowserApp(MyNavigator)
    : createAppContainer(MyNavigator);

Comment: Hello @Mike , is `react-navigation` working with Next.js, specially with `@expo/next-adapter`?

Answer (score 1):

There is `import { Platform } from 'react-native'`:

```
{Platform.OS === 'web' ? (
  <Text
    style={styles.link}
    accessibilityRole="link"
    href={`/alternate`}
  >
    A universal link
  </Text>
) : (
  <Button
    title="Go to Details"
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate("alternate")}
  />
)}
```

Comment: Would I need to do this for the imports as well? I wouldn't want the web bundles to be bloated with unused imports

Comment: @Mike Just `import { Platform }` where you want to use its functionality.

Comment: I meant the actual components. Since they will be different I wouldn't want to import native components on web. Maybe webpack would be smart enough to tree shake that out

Comment: @Mike That would be great if you can find and show your found solution how to do that!